# Get the children of a specific store group in Extjs5

Tags: grid, store, children, extjs5

I am having an issue in Extjs5 when retrieving a specific group data from my store using  `getGroups()` function.

In Extjs 4 it works fine :

`Ext.getCmp('Grid').getStore().getGroups(groupName).children;`

But when I am using `Extjs5` I can't assign a parameter to the `getGroups()` and I can't get its children.

How can I get the children of a specific store group in Extjs5 ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to change the getGroups to make it work.

```
 Ext.define('Ext.csx.data.BufferedJsonStore', {
 extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

 getGroups: function (requestGroupString) {
    if (!this.data.items) {
        return [];
    }
    this.callParent(arguments);
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for [`Store.getGroups`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-method-getGroups), it returns an array of the grouped data. So you can find a specific group, and its children, by looping through the array to find an entry with the `name` property set to the group name, then getting the `children` property of that.

Or you could simply apply a filter to the store, based on the group field.

Comment: Thank you.I do it by using a loop to go through objects in an array